# cant get picture of android camera as i get on preview

Tags: android, camera

can someone please explain to me how to get a picture the as same as I get on the preview?
I'm trying for days to understand how it works but I'm getting nowhere.

It goes like this, I see the image on the camera preview before getting the picture but when I take the picture it is different, the sides are cropped or something.

What I understand is that there are 2 params I must set, `setPreviewSize` and `setPictureSize`, if I set the preview too big it crushes, so if I set it with something that fits the screen the resolution is a little blurry for a picture so I set a bigger resolution for picture size and it is there where I get a different picture from what I see in the camera preview, but if I set in picture size the same as preview size I get exactly the same.

Obviously there is something I'm not getting well

Comment: Please share your code, how are you trying to achieve this!

Comment: sorry i was out working, the proyect is not my, i was hired to finish it and it haves to much garbache, i will have to much lines, if you dont care i will upload it